# ShareThis not working after installing Turbolinks gem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, sharethis, turbolinks

I've recently installed the turbolinks and jquery-turbolinks gems and now my ShareThis button doesn't popup like it used to when clicking.

I've currently have these ShareThis scripts in my application.html.erb head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=false;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "eonwofenaoenf-oenfwoafneo-woenfowenfe"});</script>
```

Here is the code on my show.html.erb page:

```
<span class='st_sharethis_custom'></span>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I inspected button.js and found the way to make it like this way.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=false;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "eonwofenaoenf-oenfwoafneo-woenfowenfe"});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight && (stLight.readyRun = false)</script>
```

And span tag is same as yours.

```html
<span class='st_sharethis_custom'></span>
```

But above solution is pretty weak against the change to button.js's workflow in sharethis side.

So, when you compare share button vs page loading speed and share button importance won page load speed, then disabling turbolinks is a good solution.